# OAuth Request and Access Tokens

Tags: oauth, token, access-token

I want to implement `oauth 1` in my website and I was just wondering if 
I have to change the `request token` once it was exchange to an `access token`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Request tokens are meant to be temporary and unique.  After giving one out, you should forget all about it once either a) a few minutes have passed or b) it was used to request an access token.  Allowing reuse of request tokens would open you up to http replay attacks.

Section 6 of the OAuth 1.0 spec spells this out:

> **Request Token:** Used by the Consumer to
>   ask the User to authorize access to
>   the Protected Resources. The
>   User-authorized Request Token is
>   exchanged for an Access Token, MUST
>   only be used once, and MUST NOT be
>   used for any other purpose. It is
>   RECOMMENDED that Request Tokens have a
>   limited lifetime.

Comment: follow up question sir. If I have an access token which is an expired one and I refreshed it meaning I exchange it again for another access token so I wouldnt go through the first and second steps of oauth. Question is does the value of the new access token differs from the expired access token?

Comment: yes, you should issue an updated access token and forget about the expired one